# access variable member "*" in template

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

i have a variable

```
var1 = {
  '*'                   = >        {
    'counter'           = >        {
      'default'     = > '0',
      'description' = > 'test'
     }
   }
 }
```

in perl template toolkit.
How can i access the content of '*' in the template.

```
[% var1.*.counter %]
```

does not work because of the symbol is no valid name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define a variable to be equal to `*` within the template, and use that instead.

```
[% star = '*' %]
[% var1.$star.counter.description %]
```

But I wonder why you *have* to have an asterisk as a key in the first place? It would be far better to provide a sensible key at the Perl level, perhaps by writing

```
$vars->{var1}{star} = $vars->{var1}{'*'}
```

before you call the Template Toolkit.

Comment: the toolkit uses XML as input,  transfers it into a hash structure to feed the templates. The node with the name  attribute "*" has a special meaning.

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: Then it is because you are using *values* as *keys*, which is unwise.

Comment: you may be right but the xml defines some datastructures, so the values are normally valid identifiers. The star-member should stand for the default initialization of array members

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: If you were using XML *identifiers* as hash keys that would be fine, but attribute values can be any string and it's not appropriate to use them like this. You can process XML into any Perl data structure you like using, say, `XML::Twig` or `XML::LibXML`, but I'm beginning to suspect that you're using the awful `XML::Simple`, whose own documentation says that it shouldn't be used in new projects. However it looks like you may have gone too far along this path for it to be worthwhile changing tack now, especially if this is the only anomaly you have encountered.

Comment: your suggestion with the variable interpolation took me to the expression `[% var1.${'*'}.counter.description %]`.

Comment: Actual we are using `XML::LibXML` but we parse the xml-structure and transform it into a hash based tree structure. We have a special way how to define and handle enumerations. Within such a enumeration the element nodes are identified (and put into the hash) by the name attribute that by definition has to be a valid c-identifier (with the only exception of the now-new asterisk extension).

Comment: @vlad_tepesch: Your solution is excellent. Please post it as an answer to your own question and accept it. Do you have a reference to the module documentation that describes that syntax?

Comment: it is just an combination of the expression you posted. `[% var1.$star.counter%]` is just an abbreviation of `[% var1.${star}.counter %]` where the curly brackets can be used to clearyfy which part belongs to the variable to interpolate and which to the surrounding expression. so i just inserted your separate variable definition into this expression. http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_Variable_Interpolation So i suggest simply to add it to your solution as remark